# Do "Nani o tabetai" and "Nani ga tabetai" have the same meaning?

Tags: translation, particle-が, particle-を

Sometimes you see japanese people (or japanese descendant I guess) writing
*nani ga tabetai desuka?* and sometimes they write
*Nani o tabetai desu ka?*

Is there any difference in meaning, nuance or emphasis in these 2 sentences or do they mean exactly the same thing?